# How to attach an embedded link in XML

Tags: xml, hyperlink

For example:

p
The kids went to school.
/p

How do I attach an embedded link to school? 
Should I create an element called, for example 'link', and paste the URL as an attribute of school?

Like this:

p
The kids went to
Link url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoolschool" school /Link
/p